# How to sort & Group in Android?

Tags: android, listview, sorting

I have ArrayList and I want to sort and group all data by header in Android.
How it is possible in Android? please help me.below me from owner And set header Me And Joe Manager From owner And set Header in listview. How to do that in Android?

[image]

My code in below::

```
public class Request extends Activity {
    private String assosiatetoken;
    private ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list = new ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>();
    ListView lv;
    Button back;
    private Spinner spndata;
    String[] reqspinner = { "Request Date", "Last Update", "Type", "Owner",
            "State" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.request);
        assosiatetoken = MyApplication.getToken();

        new doinbackground(this).execute();

        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spndata = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.list_all_quize_req);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reqspinner);
        spndata.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listrequestdata);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent edit = new Intent(Request.this, Request_webview.class);
                // edit.putExtra("Cat_url", url_link);

                startActivity(edit);
            }
        });

        spndata.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate1);
                    // Collections.reverse(list);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        if (list.get(i).submitDate != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i).lastModifiedDate != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate3);
                    // Collections.reverse(list);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i).state != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                getApplicationContext(), list));

                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }

        });
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            java.util.Date d2 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
                d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1); // descending
            // return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1); //ascending
        }
    };
    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate1 = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            java.util.Date d2 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.submitDate);
                d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.submitDate);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1); // descending
            // return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1); //ascending
        }
    };
    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate3 = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            String d1 = null;
            String d2 = null;
            d1 = ord1.state;
            d2 = ord2.state;
            return d1.compareToIgnoreCase(d2);
        }
    };

    class doinbackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        private Context ctx;

        public doinbackground(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.cancel();

        }

    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list;

        public MyListAdapter(Context mContext,
                ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();

        }

        public All_Request_data_dto getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_request_data, null);
            TextView req_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.req_txt);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_txt);
            TextView owner = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.owner_txt);
            TextView state = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.state_txt);

            req_id.setText(list.get(position).requestId + " - "
                    + list.get(position).title);
            date.setText(list.get(position).lastModifiedDate + " - "
                    + list.get(position).submitDate);
            owner.setText(list.get(position).owner);
            state.setText(list.get(position).state);

            // }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Look up Section Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make separate list for each category and make a list of these lists and make another list for category names than you can you use ExpandableListView and Adapter for this is like bellow. Here in example, it is used 2d array you can replace this with your list.

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context myContext;
String[][] arrChildelements;
String[] arrGroup;

public ExpAdapter(Context context, String[] arrGroup, String[][] arrChild) {
    myContext = context;
    this.arrGroup = arrGroup;
    this.arrChildelements = arrChild;
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    return arrChildelements[groupPosition].length;
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return arrGroup.length;
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
    }

    TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
    tvGroupName.setText(arrGroup[groupPosition]);

    return convertView;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }

    TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
    tvPlayerName.setText(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: it is adapter you can make separate class. lists you have to make yourself. darek category mate alag alag list banav

Comment: for make list with unique data   HashSet<String> hasSet = new HashSet<String>(old_list);
  new_list= new ArrayList<String>(hasSet);

Answer (score 0):

you have to write down your own `Adapter`. You can extends the `BaseAdapter`, for instance, and override the following methods:

- `getCount()` it iwill returns the number of items in your dataset
- `getView()` it will inflates your view
- `getItemViewType()` Get the type of View that will be created by getView() (the group element Baroque/Classic in your example) or the "normal" item.
- `getViewTypeCount ()` the number of type of Views you have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you try to short your list then try this for string

```
public void sort(List<arraylist> itemLocationList) {
    if(itemLocationList!=null)
    {
        Collections.sort(itemLocationList, new Comparator<arraylist>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(list o1, list o2) {
                return o1.res_name.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.res_name);
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got solution on my question .Thanks Jignesh!!!

```
public class Request extends Activity {
    private String assosiatetoken;
    private ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list = new ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>();
    ListView lv;
    ExpandableListView exlistView;
    ArrayList<String> catOwner = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> uniCatOner = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>> masterOwner = new ArrayList<ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>>();
    ArrayList<String> catState = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> uniCatState = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>> masterState = new ArrayList<ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>>();
    Button back;
    private Spinner spndata;
    String[] reqspinner = { "Request Date", "Last Update", "Type", "Owner",
            "State" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ExpAdapter expAdapter;

    private void setOwner() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            catOwner.add(list.get(i).owner);
        }

        HashSet<String> hasSetstate = new HashSet<String>(catOwner);
        uniCatOner = new ArrayList<String>(hasSetstate);

        for (String str : uniCatOner) {
            ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> cats = new ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>();
            masterOwner.add(cats);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < uniCatOner.size(); j++) {
                if (uniCatOner.get(j).equals(list.get(i).owner)) {
                    masterOwner.get(j).add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setState() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            catState.add(list.get(i).state);
        }

        HashSet<String> hasSetstate = new HashSet<String>(catState);
        uniCatState = new ArrayList<String>(hasSetstate);

        for (String str1 : uniCatState) {
            ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> cats = new ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>();
            masterState.add(cats);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < uniCatState.size(); j++) {
                if (uniCatState.get(j).equals(list.get(i).state)) {
                    masterState.get(j).add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.request);
        assosiatetoken = MyApplication.getToken();
        list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
        exlistView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);

        setOwner();
        setState();

        new doinbackground(this).execute();

        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spndata = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.list_all_quize_req);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reqspinner);
        spndata.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listrequestdata);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent edit = new Intent(Request.this, Request_webview.class);
                // edit.putExtra("Cat_url", url_link);

                startActivity(edit);
            }
        });

        spndata.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate1);
                    exlistView.setFocusable(false);
                    // Collections.reverse(list);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        if (list.get(i).submitDate != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    exlistView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i).lastModifiedDate != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    exlistView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Collections.sort(list, byDate3);
                    // Collections.reverse(list);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i).state != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:

                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    expAdapter = new ExpAdapter(Request.this, uniCatOner,
                            masterOwner);
                    exlistView.setAdapter(expAdapter);
                    break;
                case 4:

                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    expAdapter = new ExpAdapter(Request.this, uniCatState,
                            masterState);
                    exlistView.setAdapter(expAdapter);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }

        });
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            java.util.Date d2 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
                d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1); // descending
            // return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1); //ascending
        }
    };
    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate1 = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            java.util.Date d2 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.submitDate);
                d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.submitDate);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1); // descending
            // return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1); //ascending
        }
    };
    static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate3 = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
        public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
            String d1 = null;
            String d2 = null;
            d1 = ord1.state;
            d2 = ord2.state;
            return d1.compareToIgnoreCase(d2);
        }
    };

    class doinbackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        private Context ctx;

        public doinbackground(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.cancel();

        }

    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list;

        public MyListAdapter(Context mContext,
                ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();

        }

        public All_Request_data_dto getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_request_data, null);
            TextView req_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.req_txt);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_txt);
            TextView owner = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.owner_txt);
            TextView state = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.state_txt);

            req_id.setText(list.get(position).requestId + " - "
                    + list.get(position).title);
            date.setText(list.get(position).lastModifiedDate + " - "
                    + list.get(position).submitDate);
            owner.setText(list.get(position).owner);
            state.setText(list.get(position).state);

            // }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```